# Keyboard dead through software?

Tags: keyboard, windows-10

I have a relatively new MSI-Laptop with W10 which has issues I never experienced before: recently the kbd stopped working (external USB as well as internal)! I rebooted several times, but it would not work. (Also unplugged the external USB-kbd etc.)
When I finally unplugged everything...somehow it worked again, but after short time died again. After restart, it worked again and has been working since for several days now.

I have spoken to MSI-Support who suggested to pick it up and repair. But I hesitate to do so because I have spent quite some time to set it up as it is - and I wonder if it really is a hardware-issue. Google has a few hits for dying kbd under W10 and I see a few posts here - but I wonder if it has been accepted anywhere at MS as a problem and if there will ever be a fix for it. Or should I try to get the machine repaired?